# Each image is repeated twice, in preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<template class="img-template">
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="" />
    <a class="remove-img"><i class="material-icons">close</i></a>
</div>
```

```
<div>
    <label>Image</label>
</div>
<input id="photoInput" class="imgSelector" type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg" data-preview="previewPhoto" data-multiple="true">
<div id="previewPhoto" class="imgPreview" data-model-prop="PhotosJson"></div>
<input hidden asp-for="PhotosJson" />
```

I have 3 elements: An `input` element for selecting image, a `div` for image preview, and a hidden `input` for storing serialized of an array contains string(basse64) of all images in this part.
**Jquery:**
in `documentReady`:

```
$('.imgSelector').on('change', previewPhotoInputAndFill);
```

And the function body is:

```
   function previewPhotoInputAndFill() {
        var $currentInput = $(this);
        var previewSelector = $currentInput.data('preview');
        var $preview = $('#' + previewSelector);

         if (this.files) {
            var files = this.files;
            $.each(files, function (i, file) {
                var size = (file.size) / 1000;
                if (size > 100) {
                    return alert("err msg!");
                }
                if (!/\.(jpeg|jpg)$/i.test(file.name)) {
                    return alert("err msg!");
                }
                var reader = new FileReader();
                $(reader).on("load", function () {
                    var imgSource = this.result;
                    var isMultiple = $currentInput.data('multiple');
                    if (isMultiple === true) {
                        $preview.append($('.img-template').html());
                    } else {
                        $preview.html($('.img-template').html());
                    }
                    var $lastDiv = $preview.find(".img-container:last");
                    $lastDiv.find('img').attr('src', imgSource);
                    var imgSources = [];
                    $preview.find('img').each(function (index, element) {
                        imgSources.push($(element).attr('src').split(',')[1]);
                    });
                    var modelProp = $preview.data('model-prop');
                    var $modelProp = $('#' + modelProp);
                    $modelProp.val(JSON.stringify(imgSources));
                });
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            });
        }
    }
```

The problem is that, when I select an image, it's repeated twice.

Comment: It seems that problem lies somewhere else, it's working fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/qxns8f2c/

Comment: It was called by another 'onchange', too.